# HTTP Status 403 - Forbidden - jdbc realm setup with glassfish-v3

Tags: java, security, jdbc, glassfish

Hi guys i am just experimenting with some security features using glassfish, such as to block off access to a webpage to everyone apart from an authorized user, the main point of this exercise is just to get an understanding of how this can work

i have followed the following tutorial to set up my glassfish server and also the web.xml file etc

http://blog.gamatam.com/2009/11/jdbc-realm-setup-with-glassfish-v3.html

while i have set this up as per the settings i have noticed one weird issue

when trying to get access to the `/test/newxhtml.xhtml` i get the correct username / password prompt but when i enter the user and password of admin i am greeted with the 403 page forbidden, however i have noticed that if i type the username / password wrong it re prompts me for the username and password

basically i am wondering if this sounds right and instead of a 403 error can i display the webpage, and display the 403 if the user enters the wrong username and password

thanks guys

EDIT

i have noticed in the console i get the error :

```
WARNING:   No Principals mapped to Role [ADMIN].
WARNING:   No Principals mapped to Role [USER].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, yes there was no mappings configured, added the right mappings in glassfish-web.xml and now it works :)